# Rendered node display for anonymous users?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, organic-groups

I would like to use a view field (node reference to an og group, configured to display a teaser) as rendered node inside a view and display the view to anonymous users. 
Do you know how to achieve this result ?

PS. Currently I can display it for admin user but for non-admin users the view field doesn't appear.

Comment: PS2. all users including anonymous have permissions to display both nodes (og group and custom node) and the view, still the rendered node field is not displaying in a view.

Comment: Have you tried giving all permissions to a user group and see if that will enable it? Is "admin-users" user 1 or a group of users?

Comment: @googletorp what I am looking for is a tutorial showing how to create in Drupal 7 a view of nodes with a rendered field that renders organic group node teaser inside the view row. I would like to create a view that lists nodes (og group content) assigned to different og groups and shows teaser of og group content in each row.

Comment: @googletorp I think I just managed  to eliminate the problem with permissions above (somehow intuitively, maybe updating display suite or some other module to the latest dev version helped?) but I would like to learn how to do this kind of views including og related content in a more controlled way. That is why I was looking for a tutorial here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is working for admins, but not for non admins, you problem is most likely permission. Do the users have permission to see the node? Maybe they need a special permission to see nodes via relationships?

To fix this, you need to tweak your permissions.

If you want to change the way a field is rendered, either on an entity or in a view, you need to create what's called a field formatter, which essentially is a theming function for fields.

Comment: Thanks, I also think this is permissions related but the point is there are no special permissions to display nodes via relationships I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the field_permissions module installed make sure you check the settings for your view field and that the "view any value for field x" is checked for Anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping the node, and see if there are any fields that your anonymous users can't see.

Answer (score 0):

The display suite extras module creates a lot of field specific permissions. If some fields are missing, maybe its because the ds permission was not properly set.

**View Title on Node** is a new permission, for example. In my installation it was not set for anonymous users.